# License for components in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, user-controls, controls

I want to create a license system for some components (in DLL format) for ASP.NET , and I have not any ideea of about how to do this thing.
I can use the unique series of car (such as HDD's series), so it would be a pretty difficult task.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a start:

http://www.developer.com/net/net/article.php/3074001/Applications-Licensing-using-the-NET-Framework.htm (read all four pages)

And a qucick example on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.licenseprovider.aspx